# How do you set a variable default value in LESS Css

Tags: less

I am using LessPHP and I want to essentially do the following:

```
@var = "new val";

if(isnull(@var)){
 @var = "default";
}
```

I know there is no "isnull" or "if" statements. I also know that you can use parametric functions, but I want to work with @var in the global scope.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Less in LessPHP but as I remember there isn't any if statements. SASS (sass-lang.com/) is much more familiar with it